# One hot encoding alternatives for large categorical values?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, dimensionality-reduction, many-categories

Hi have dataframe with large categorical values over 1600 categories is there any way I can find alternatives so that I don't have over 1600 columns.

I found this below interesting link
 http://amunategui.github.io/feature-hashing/#sourcecode

But they are converting to class/object which I don't want. I want my final output as a dataframe so that I can test with different machine learning models?

Is there anyway I can implement ?

Comment: What are you using the categorical values for? input to another classifier? or you directly want to use the 1-of-1600 categories? or ... ?

Comment: @HughPerkins type of service customer enrolled for.

Comment: that answers the question 'what do the categories represent?' but not my intended question of 'how are you going to use the output of this network?'

Comment: I like to consider my output variable and then look at one-hot ecoding subsets using variable importance.  I have been able to get columns that would have O(nCr(20,3)) candidates for one-hot into being 3 columns in this way though it was very data dependent.  The variable importance saw ~1100 columns, but then returned the important ones, which were 3 columns.  That was much more human-understandable, and substantially improved prediction quality.

Comment: If you use sparse matrices 1600 columns isn't a problem